# Can my PC get hacked by just clicking on a malicious/virus link? (2020 Update)

Tags: web, developer-tools, websecurity

I will rephase for a more precisely question. If I click on a malicious/virus link, then I do not click on anything further or download anything from that website, can my PC get hacked?
I am asking this question on the perspective of a web developer through all the tools and programming languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If browsers work as intended, there shouldn't be, but there's always the risk that someone has exploited a vulnerability in a web browser that has gone undetected or unreported. Such vulnerabilities do occur, though most get fixed quickly.

It's highly unlikely that you'd just stumble upon such an exploit, but it's always best to be safe. If you don't know or trust the link, it's best to just not click it.

There is nothing standard that would allow a developer to hack or infect a client computer through a browser simply by the client loading the page.